# Python-Celery: How to read logging info logged by other modules

Tags: python, logging, celery

I have a celery task, `operation`, as below:

```
# tasks.py

@app.task(bind=True, name='operation')
def operation(self, request):
    custom_library = CustomLibrary()
    res = custom_library.foo(request)
    return res
```

as shown in the code snippet above, the celery task calls a custom library function `custom_library.foo()`. The function `foo()` uses Python `logging` to log some info such as percentage of progress in format of, for example, `"PROGRESS %58"`:

```
# custom_library.py

class CustomLibrary:
    # __init__() and all other methods are removed here for readability
    def foo(request):
         # There were some things being done here that are removed for readability
         logging.info("PROGRESS %58") # This is just an example. The progress is updated dynamically.
```

The Celery task is called by `manage()` function in another module as below:

```
   # scheduler.py

   def manage(request):
       operation.s(request).apply_async()

   def get_logging_info():
       # get all info from Python logging and return
```

Now, I would like to have a `get_logging_info()` function that is able to have access to the `PROGRESS` info that is logged by the `custom_library.foo()` function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just calling `logging.info` on the module level with no added arguments logs with the root logger to a default StreamHandler. If you want to catch that log you need to attach some handler that stores the message somewhere to the root logger. `MemoryHandler` for example, or write them to a file.

Comment: What's the error you're facing?

Comment: So... you are using the logging framework to pass information to your scheduler... While doable I advise against it. Rather write your progress update to a message queue and that way you will inform the scheduler (or whatever service is on the other end) of the updates.